# Mongodb elemMatch not reading variable from aggregate root

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to build an aggregate query from a `users` collection. Each user has an `id` property that is associated in a `clients` collection array:

```json
// users...
[
  {
    id: '12345',
    name: 'John'
  }
  // ...
}
```

```json
// clients...
[
  {
    name: 'Foo',
    members: [ { id: '1234', role: 'Admin' } ]
  },
  // ....
]
```

So what I'm trying to do is aggregate the `users` collection and do a `$lookup` to "join" the clients with which a user is a member (by the `id`)

```js
db.users.aggregate([
  $lookup: {
      from: 'clients',
      as: 'clients',
      let: { user_id: '$id' },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            members: {
              $elemMatch: { id: '$user_id' },
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    };
}])
```

If I hard-code any user's id into the `$elemMatch` (replacing `$user_id`) it works, but I can't seem to get it to work as a variable from the `user` records.

Comment: It's double $$ in the nested pipeline: `$elemMatch: { id: '$$user_id' },`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`$lookup` let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#std-label-lookup-join-let),

> A $match stage requires the use of an $expr operator to access the variables. The $expr operator allows the use of aggregation expressions inside of the $match syntax.

From your scenario,

1. Need **`$expr`** to access the variable.
2. Apply the **`$in`** operator instead of `$elemMatch`.
3. To reference the variable in the pipeline, use **`$$<variable>`** but not `$<variable>`.

```
{
  $match: {
    $expr: {
      $in: [
        "$$user_id",
        "$members.id"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6RYWnRNM9Jh)